# Obstruction in construction of some lattices, related with $K3$ surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices, quadratic-forms, k3-surfaces

I am considering a certain $K3$ surface that is lattice-polarized in two ways.
This leads to the following simple problem in lattice theory:

(Let me borrow notations for lattice from Ch.14 of this [book](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/huybrech/K3Global.pdf)).

For a given $N \in \mathbb N$, I would like to construct an *even* lattice $L$ of signature $(1,2)$ such that

a) $L$ contains *primitive* sublattices $L_1, L_2$ that are isomorphic to $U(2)$ respectively,

b) $L_1 \cap L_2 = \langle \xi \rangle$ with $(\xi.\xi) \ge 2 N$.

c) $L$ does not have an element $e$ with $(e.e)=-2$.

I tried to construct such a lattice $L$ but couldn't succeed even in case of $N=1$.

So I am wondering:

> Is  there any obstruction in construction of such a lattice $L$?

I have also a general question about Picard lattice of $K3$ surfaces.
According to Nikulin, every even lattice of rank $r$ with $r\le 11$ and signature $(1, r-1)$ comes as the Picard lattice of some $K3$ surfaces.

> Are there any methods to find all such lattices?  (of rank $r$ with $r\le 11$ and signature $(1, r-1)$ and some fixed discriminants?)

Comment: What do you mean by $L_1, L_2$ are isomorphic to $U(2)$? The former are Abelian groups, the latter is non-Abelian.

Comment: Here, $U$ is the hyperbolic plane. Please see p. 282 of the book linked above for its definition.